# RunAs username from variable

Tags: vbscript, runas

I am writing a script to run IE as a different user. At the beginning script displays Input, and I would like to use value from input as a username.

```
Option explicit
Dim Input, europe

Input = InputBox("Please type mailbox name")

europe = "EUROPE\" & Input 

Dim oShell
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "RunAs /profile /user:" & europe &  "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
WScript.Sleep 100
oShell.Sendkeys Input
oShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.Quit
```

As you can see username is on domain `EUROPE\` and password is the same as username.

So username should look like this `EUROPE\ & Input`, and password `& Input`

I have trouble getting a string from variable and passing it to shell command.

Answer (score 0):

OK, managed to do that. If you want to put string from variable as a username you need to put it like this:

```
oShell.Run "RunAs /profile /user:" & europe &" ""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```